# How can my brother and I add each other's contacts to our contact lists, most productively?

Tags: world-of-warships

My brother and I each have at least 100 Contacts on our Contacts list, some duplicates but mostly not. It's obviously unproductive to add at least 100 usernames singly. How can we copy and paste them in one stroke?

Assume that my brother's ID is 1, and mine 2. We tried these steps:

1. We went to C:\World of Warships\profile.
2. We saw `chat_pref_1_wowsna.loc.xml` and `chat_pref_2_wowsna.loc.xml`. We opened them in Notepad.
3. I copied all Items under `<rosterLocal>` from `chat_pref_1_wowsna.loc.xml`  and pasted them to `chat_pref_2_wowsna.loc.xml`. My brother did vice versa. We saved.
4. But after we started the game, these  files automatically reverted without the pasted Items! Our pasted new Items disappeared! Why?

[image]

Comment: Yet another username on another site. Please respond this time: what’s the point? Why not just use a single username?